# java.lang.NullPointerException when download large file

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to push file from website to android device. Note that I push during my app is close/in background/exit. I'm using service to receive the notification. File success downloaded using Asynctask :

```
private static class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String notiType = null;

    String dlink = null;
    String fileName = null;

    private WeakReference<MyFirebaseMessagingService> activityReference;


    DownloadFileTask(MyFirebaseMessagingService context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG, "DownloadFile");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... payload) {

        int count;
        String filePath = null;
        notiType = payload[0];
        dlink = payload[1];
        fileName = payload[2];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(dlink);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            OutputStream output = null;

            switch (notiType) {
                case Notification_001:
                    filePath = activityReference.get().getFileDir("/DownloadedFiles", fileName);
                    break;

                case Notification_002:
                    filePath = activityReference.get().getFileDir("/DownloadedAPK", fileName);
                    break;

                   default:

                    break;
            }

            if (filePath != null) {
                File myFile = new File(filePath);
                if (myFile.exists()) {
                    myFile.delete();
                    Log.d(TAG, "file exist. delete it first");
                }
            }

            output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
        }

        return filePath;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (file_url == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DownloadFile Error");
            activityReference.get().setToast("ERROR downloading file.. URL is invalid.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "DownloadFile Finish");
            File file = new File(file_url);
            if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {


                switch (notiType) {

                    case Notification_001:

                            if (activityReference.get().isAppInForeground) {


                            }           

                            Log.d(TAG, "Task finish");                         
                        break;
                    case Notification_002:
                       break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }

        } else{

            activityReference.get().setToast("File downloaded but file has 0 size.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

However I am facing problem in PostExecute method where I can't invoke native method for example `activityReference.get().isAppInForeground`. I have the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xk.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService$DownloadFileTask.onPostExecute(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:342)
    at xk.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService$DownloadFileTask.onPostExecute(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:228)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The exception often occurs when file having size like 17k KB but small size like 10 KB won't having problem in invoke method.

Thanks...

Comment: `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:342` what is on this line?

Comment: activityReference.get().isAppInForeground @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: `activityReference` becomes null over time

Comment: Thank u for telling me that ! :)  I was able to solve by using appreferences instead  of activityReference